# Try to understand Kafka Scala Syntax

Tags: scala, apache-kafka

I have been going through Kafka source code of the `Log` class in core module of Kafka project but I am still new to scala.
I have encountered a syntax which is quite hard to understand.
Here is the code snippets:

snippet 1:

```scala
    // Now do a second pass and load all the log and index files.
    // We might encounter legacy log segments with offset overflow (KAFKA-6264). We need to split such segments. When
    // this happens, restart loading segment files from scratch.
    retryOnOffsetOverflow {
      // In case we encounter a segment with offset overflow, the retry logic will split it after which we need to retry
      // loading of segments. In that case, we also need to close all segments that could have been left open in previous
      // call to loadSegmentFiles().
      logSegments.foreach(_.close())
      segments.clear()
      loadSegmentFiles()
    }
```

snippet2:

```scala
 private[log] def retryOnOffsetOverflow[T](fn: => T): T = {
    while (true) {
      try {
        return fn// what is fn here in context of code snippet 1?
      } catch {
        case e: LogSegmentOffsetOverflowException =>
          info(s"Caught segment overflow error: ${e.getMessage}. Split segment and retry.")
          splitOverflowedSegment(e.segment)//##!!!1.return a List[Segement], but where does this return goes?
      }
    }
    throw new IllegalStateException()
  }
```

1. What I found hard to understand is that how the method `retryOnOffsetOverflow` is called in snippet 1 and what is passed to it as the argument of its param? <del>I know the param of `retryOnOffsetOverflow` is a function but here in this snippet what is the argument passed to this function?</del>
2. Also I am not clear what is the return of `retryOnOffsetOverflow` here? The return is `T` which is kind of a generic? I am not sure what is the return of `retryOnOffsetOverflow` here, will it be different according to fact that it caught the exception or not? If so what will exactly be the return respectively?

Thank a lot for the explanation and please tell me if I missed the necessary code to answer the question.

---

**updated**: I would rectify my self that the  param of `retryOnOffsetOverflow` is a by-name parameter which won't be evaluated unless and until it is referenced somewhere in the body of the method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upd.: Slightly changed last part, as looks like it would load "splitted" files right in the next loop iteration.

1. Param for `retryOnOffsetOverflow` here is everything inside curly braces - basically, these three lines of code - that's the function `(fn: => T)`, that it accepts.
2. `retryOnOffsetOverflow` is trying to execute function, that was passed, and returns it's answer, if the execution was successful. One part that's a bit difficult to understand - when there's an exception, `splitOverflowedSegment` is called not for it return type, but for the fact that it "mutates state" in `replaceSegments` function. This segments would be read on the next loop iteration restart, in `loadSegmentFiles` function.

Comment: Yeah thanks a lot, it is a clear explanation. I see that the splitter files is reload by `loadSegmentFiles ()` in the next loop. But one more question is when will the loop in `retryOnOffsetOverflow ()` ends? Till it met the Exception on the last line of the method?

Comment: Till `fn` function would be executed successfully. If it will finish, `return` would be executed, breaking the loop.

Comment: All right, I finally see the logic of the `retryOnOffsetOverflow ` method, so it keeps execute `fn` in a infinite loop, and each time `fn` cannot successfully executed, it will catch the exception and update the state of the Segments for the next round of the loop, and in the end `fn` will run without any exception and that's when `retryOnOffsetOverflow ` ends. Am I getting it correct?

Comment: Yep, I think you're correct (at least I'm understanding this code in the same way).

Comment: Also, not sure what last "IllegalState" exception stands for - I don't see a path where this exception can be thrown.

Comment: @Rayan Ral can you help and suggest how to handle this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62036791/while-writing-to-hdfs-path-getting-error-java-io-ioexception-failed-to-rename

Answer (score 2):

> What I found hard to understand is that how the method retryOnOffsetOverflow is called in snippet 1 and what is passed to it as the argument of its param? I know the param of retryOnOffsetOverflow is a function but here in this snippet what is the argument passed to this function?

Consider following simplified example

```scala
def printTillSuccess[T](fn: => T): T = {
  while (true) {
    val result = fn
    println(result)
    return result
  }
  throw new Exception("dead end")
}

printTillSuccess("a")
printTillSuccess({ "a" })
printTillSuccess { "a" }
```

`fn: => T` is not a function but a [by-name](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/by-name-parameters.html) parameter. It will be evaluated on each reference, ie at line `val result = fn`. Functions in Scala have an `apply` method and this not the case here.

You can pass values into a method via `()`, and this is done in example `printTillSuccess("a")`.

Scala allows wrapping any block of code with `{}` and the last statement will be used as result of the block. Thus, `{"a"}` is same as `"a"`.

So, now you can pass `{"a"}` into methods, thus `printTillSuccess({ "a" })` is a valid call.

And finally, Scala allows for substitution of `()` with block definitions `{}` in methods and this opens syntax `printTillSuccess { "a" }`.

> Also I am not clear what is the return of retryOnOffsetOverflow here?
>   The return is T which is kind of a generic? I am not sure what is the
>   return of retryOnOffsetOverflow here, will it be different according
>   to fact that it caught the exception or not? If so what will exactly
>   be the return respectively?

The return type is the type of the by-name parameter and it's `T`. And statement `return fn` is the only place that defines `T`.

In case of `LogSegmentOffsetOverflowException`, the catch will be called and `splitOverflowedSegment` executed. This will mutate some internal state and next iteration of `while(true)` will evaluate the by-name parameter again. So, the exception does not change the return type but allows for the next iteration to happen.

The `while` loop can only exit when `fn` evaluates successfully or a different exception is thrown. In any case, the return, if happens, will be of `T`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for such an elaborating and easy to understand tutorial lol. I get it much  clearer. That's really helpful. Well, I must say scala is so flexible.Sigh.

Answer (score 1):

```
def retryOnOffsetOverflow[T](fn: => T): T
```

`retryOnOffsetOverflow()` is a method that take a single "by name" parameter, which means that the parameter won't be evaluated unless and until it is referenced somewhere in the body of the method.

So `fn` might be a single value and it might be multiple lines of code, and it will remain un-evaluated (un-executed) until here `try { return fn }`, where it is executed wrapped in a `try`.

The `fn` evaluation will result in value of some type. It doesn't really matter what that type is (we'll call it `T`) but  `retryOnOffsetOverflow()` is required to return the same type.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So you mean `retryOnOffsetOverflow() ` is required to return the same type as its param which is the return of all statements in the curly bracket? ` logSegments.foreach(_.close())  segments.clear()  loadSegmentFiles()`

Comment: Essentially yes. If `fn` returns a value (or evaluates to a value), that value, of type `T`, is returned from `retryOnOffsetOverflow()`. If `fn` throws, and it is caught (so it must have been a `LogSegmentOffsetOverflowException`) then the `splitOverflowedSegment()` must return a value of the same type `T` that `fn` was supposed to return.